# .Net Maui .Net7 - Button View: I can not wrap text. LineBreakMode is not working for me

Tags: button, maui, word-wrap, .net-7.0

I need a button with more than 1 line of text, in .Net Maui (using .Net7). I used the property LineBreakMode = "WordWrap", but text ("wrap me if you can") does not wrap.

I followed directions in https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9102, without success. Here, they recommend using LineBreakMode="WordWrap".

What is wrong in my code?

I uploaded a example project to GitHub: https://github.com/leoderja/ButtonDoesNotWrapTextInMaui

Please, see the code and image below

```
<Button
    x:Name="CounterBtn"
    Text="Wrap me if you can"
    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    MaximumWidthRequest="100" 
    HeightRequest="200"/>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I did a test with your demo, and it is just the case as you said on uwp, but it works properly on my android emulator. So you can post a new issue on github [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) . Thanks for your support and feedback for maui.

Comment: You are wright, Jessie, but I chose Maui because I need to develop cross-platform apps, specially for windows. I will post an issue in the maui project, as you proposed. thank you a lot